# How do i find out if an appointment is private

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I use Exchange Server Managed API. How do I find out if an appointment is private?
There doesn't seem to be a method or property in the "Appointment" class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Look at the [Sensitivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.sensitivity(v=EXCHG.80).aspx) property.

Comment: To access that property you first have to call Appointment.Load(PropertySet.FirstClassProperties), or maybe load that property specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, I don't seem to be able to comment on @Stuart's answer above and didn't want to create a new question.

If you're using `ExchangeService.FindAppointments`, the returned Items are `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment`
The `Sensitivity` property seems to be at the same level?

How do you (did you @Luke) access that property please?
Do you need to use `ExchangeService.LoadPropertiesForItems` ?

Comment: Dim apartmentProperties = New PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End, AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Location, AppointmentSchema.MyResponseType, AppointmentSchema.Sensitivity)
For Each appointment In service.FindAppointments(New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, username & "@" & Domain), New CalendarView(StartDate, EndDate) With {.PropertySet = apartmentProperties}) 'Max range of 2 years